# How to hide a column in a Gridview (android)

Tags: android, gridview, hide

I've got a GridView (Android). I would like to hide one of it's columns and then access to it's values.

Is it possible?

Comment: SetVisibility, but that's for all the GridView so nothing to do with that

Comment: I put my answer below to your question, but its really hard to think of a good reason you would try to impelement this... Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm loading information from a data base an putting it into the gridview. The first column contains the ID which is useful for me to manage the data base but useless for the user. I thought not loading the ID, however I need it to do another queries. That's why I would like to hide it. (I'm trying to implement your suggestion)...I don't know if I have explained it very well...

Comment: Why not just hold your data in map?

Comment: Thank you NameSpace. I've been trying but I couldn't fix it. I think I'll change the data structure as you said. I would like to give you a vote, but I cant for being a novel.

Answer (score 0):

Update: based on your reply, I think it best you hold your data in a map, rather than using an invisible column...

Example:

```
   HashMap<Integer, Integer> map_positionToId = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   map_positionToId.put(position, id);
   int id = map_positionToId.get(position);
```

There is no easy setting to flip on gridview to make a column invisible that I am aware of. 
However, below is a suggestion to try... It may take a bit of trial and error to pull off correctly:

This is the getView method for your gridView adapter:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //You want your if(convertView == null) code here.  
        //As we can't set visibility of a null object;

       ....

        // Assuming u want to blank the 3rd column, in a 3 column gridview
        if(position % 3 == 0)  
            convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //u can try gone too?
        else
            convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // rest of your code...

   }
```

You might also play around with padding / margins, and view width, to get the desired effect if you are trying to push the invisible column off the screen.